# Drawing quad in OpenGL ES on Android

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am just trying to understand what is going on here. I have a textured quad on the screen but I am really confused why it takes up the entire screen. If my texture is 64X64 and I wanted a quad at the top left of the screen that was 64X64 what would I need to change? Is my viewport or my vertices positions causing it to take up the whole screen?

With changes so far:

```
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {

        myquad.loadGLTexture(gl, this.context);

        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_BLEND);
        gl.glBlendFunc(gl.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL10.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
        gl.glHint(GL10.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL10.GL_FASTEST);
        gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    }

    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int w, int h) {
        width=w;
        height=h;
        gl.glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        gl.glOrthof(0.0f, w, 0, h, -1.0f, 1.0f);        
    }

    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
        // define the color we want to be displayed as the "clipping wall"
        gl.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        // clear the color buffer to show the ClearColor we called above...
        gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();

        myquad.Draw(gl);
        //gl.glTranslatef(.5f, 2.0f, 0.0f);
        //gl.glScalef(.5f, .5f, 0);
    }

private float vertices[] = {
         // Vertices for the square
          -1.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,  // 0. left-bottom
           1.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,  // 1. right-bottom
          -1.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,  // 2. left-top
           1.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f   // 3. right-top
};

private float texture[] = {          
        //Mapping coordinates for the vertices
        0.0f, 1.0f,
        1.0f, 0.0f,
        1.0f, 1.0f,
        0.0f, 1.0f, 
};
public void Draw(GL10 gl)
{   
    // set the color for the triangle
    gl.glColor4f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f);

    //Enable the vertex and texture state
    gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, texturebuffer);
    gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexbuffer);

    //gl.glTranslatex(-20, 0, 0);
    // Draw the vertices as triangle strip
    gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, vertices.length / 3);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now you have your projection set up wrong. If you want to draw as if you were dealing with pixels, you would want...
this line
`gl.glOrthof(0.0f, w, -h, 0.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);`
to be more like this
`gl.glOrthof(0.0f, width, 0.0f, height, -1.0f, 1.0f);`
where width and height are the size of your context in pixels.

EDIT:
`gl.glOrthof(0.0f, w, -h, 0.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);`
has to be called after each call to glLoadIdentity().
Now you have to adjust your vertex coords. As right now they are set up to render a 1px by 1px box 1px outside the bottom left corner of the screen.

Comment: Also, and I might be wrong here, but you might also want to uncomment out your call to glMatrixMode.

Comment: Alright I made these changes and it seems to do the same thing. Why does the quad take up the whole screen and how would I draw the quad in the top left corner and have it 32X32?

Comment: Post the latest version of your source.

Comment: Alright I updated the original post to include what I have now.

Comment: gl.glOrthof(0.0f, w, 0, h, -1.0f, 1.0f);       
Has to be called after each glLoadIdentity()

Comment: You only have to do glOrthof once (well, in onSurfaceChanged in case the dimensions change).  But you do need to be in  glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION) mode first. I can't see where you've uncommented it.

Comment: It works. You guys are awesome thanks for all the help. Im new to opengl and the 3d math behind some of this still confuses me but I can manage from here I think.